# How send email with laravel ... i need send to gmail

Tags: php, laravel

I need send email with laravel to gmail but it's showing the below error:

**Error:**

> Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0
>   Must issue a STARTTLS command first. 127sm105612220wmm.45 - gsmtp "

Comment: Can you please share your configuration details with us, also show the `.env` file code here

Answer (score 3):

First login to your Gmail account and under *My account > Sign In And Security > Sign In to google*, **enable two step verification**, then you can generate app password, and you can use that app password in `.env` file.

Your `.env` a file will then look something like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=apppassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Don't forget to run `php artisan config:cache` after you make changes in your `.env` file.

Comment: MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=my email password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Comment: First login to your Gmail account and under My account > Sign In And Security > Sign In to google, enable two step verification, then you can generate app password, and you can use that app password in .env file.

Comment: Is this the safe way of sending emails via gmails smtp? Someone recommended turning off the secure app access but when I did that, someone tried to sign in to my gmail email account. I will try your safe way using 2fa

Answer (score 1):

Response code 530 indicates that you have not allowed Less Secure Apps to use your Gmail account.

You will need to enable this in your Google settings. [Here's a link](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps).

After you have allowed this, the email should go through.

---

If you're just testing, I would recommend using an SMTP testing server, such as [Mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/). It's free and will avoid the security risk that comes with allowing less secure apps to use your Gmail account.

Comment: So how do you you securely** send emails on a live production setting? I got mailtrap.io to properly send an email to a free mail trap account but I tried to use GMAILS smtp by turning off less secure apps and my account was logged into almost immediately

Answer (score 0):

Please turn on **Less secure app access** for your SMTP email account.

From the following url go to: [Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com/security)